# Express.js with csv-parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to get the data that is inside a csv file.

I send the file through Insomnia, then the `multer` is in charge of accessing the csv file and providing me with its buffer.

To get the csv data, I am using `csv-parse`.

However, despite the data appearing in the terminal, I always get the following error:

```sh
Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open 'uuid,first_name,last_name,birthday
```

I'm not really understanding what's going on.

Here is an code snippet:

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import parse from 'csv-parse'

const result = []
fs.createReadStream(msg.content).pipe(parse()).on('data', (data) => {
  data.forEach(user => {
    result.push(user)
  })
})
```

`msg.content` is the csv buffer.

Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: I think you  are trying  to pass csv content as file handle (name). if `msg.content` is not a file handle, but a whole buffer with csv inside, you should not use `fs.createReadStream`, but use [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). This should solve the issue.

Comment: I've been reading the Node.js documentation and you're right! Now it works. I ended up using the stream.PassThrough.

Comment: I'll post it as an  answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to pass csv content as file handle (name). if `msg.content` is not a file handle, but a whole buffer with csv inside, you should not use `fs.createReadStream`, but use [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). This should solve the issue.